# s3.headObject key and bucket

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am working on a lambda function that would be invoked by a S3 PUT event and would display the metadata field of the s3 object. I tried to set the key and bucket as variable but when I run it I get a `{ BadRequest: null` error. below is my code in javascript. when I hardcode the key and bucket it would work but not with variable passed in, can someone explain what am I doing wrong? thanks!

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

var srcbucket =  ("\'" + (event.Records[0].s3.object.key).toString() + "\'");
var srcKey =  ("\'" + (event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name).toString() + "\'");

console.log (srcKey);
    s3.headObject(
        {
            Bucket : srcbucket,
            Key: srcKey
        },
        function(err, data)
        {
            if (err)
            {
                console.log(err);
                context.done('Error', 'Error getting s3 object: ' + err);
            }
            else
            {
                var data = JSON.stringify(this.httpResponse.headers['x-amz-meta-checksum']).replace(/\"/g, "");
                console.log (data.replace(/\"/g, ""));
            }
```

Comment: What are you intending to accomplish with the `"\'"`?  There's no reason to wrap the values with `\'` or `'`... nor is there a reason to invoke `.toString()` on things that are *already* strings...  nor is it obvious why you have assigned `srcbucket` from `object.key` and `srckey` from `bucket.name`.

Comment: yea I mis-typed on the assigned srcbucket and srckey but I started with the correct assignment which gave me an 'Forbidden: null' error so I thought the variable wasn't parsed correctly and I started trial and error on adding the single quote on the variable string because  if I hardcode  <code> s3.headObject(
        {
            Bucket : 'srcbucket_name',
            Key: 'srcKey_name'
        }, <code>
it would work, currently with correct assignment variable 
var srckey =  event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
var srcbucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
still get a Forbidden: null'

Comment: The `'` is used when you hard code it because it's a string literal in your code.  Don't add these to an actual string.

Answer (score 0):

First, your variable is mixed up. The srcbucket is pointer to object's Key, and vice versa.
Secondly, you may want remove the additional quote `'` that was applied to the variable.

```
var srcbucket =  event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
var srcKey =  event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
```